# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Handles' - Xamarin UWP

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, uwp, isolatedstorage

We use Isolated storage throughout our code and it has always worked fine. Suddenly this error has started coming up in a few different projects and it means that I can't use Isolated Storage at all. I tried adding the System.Runtime.Handles NuGet package but it has made no difference.

This is the code:

```
        using (var userStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
        }
```

> System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException occurred
>   HResult=0x80131450   Message=Operation not permitted.   Source=   StackTrace:    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.CreatePathPrefixIfNeeded(String
>   path)    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.FetchOrCreateRoot()
>   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStore()    at
>   System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
>   at
>   Adapt.Presentation.XivicControls.XivicUtilities.CreateAttachmentsFolders()
>   in
>   C:\AdaptSource\Xivic\Adapt.Presentation.XamarinForms\Adapt\Presentation\XivicControls\XivicUtilities
>   - Xamarin Forms.cs:line 19    at Adapt.Presentation.XamarinForms.App.d__31.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\AdaptSource\Xivic\Adapt.Presentation.XamarinForms\Adapt\Presentation\XamarinForms\App.xaml.cs:line
>   99
>
> Inner Exception 1: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Runtime.Handles, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

But, this is also a compile time problem. I am getting this compiler error message in a separate project:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not copy the file
>   "C:\Users\chris.nuget\packages\runtime.any.System.Runtime.Handles\4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.3\System.Runtime.Handles.dll"
>   because it was not found. TestXamarinForms.UWP    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4222

You can easily see the error if you check out my repo here:
https://ChristianFindlay@bitbucket.org/ChristianFindlay/xamarin-forms-scratch.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved without having to do anything. I can't explain how it was resolved, but I suspect it was a problem with Appx installation. I believe that the installation of the app somehow got corrupted, and therefore the isolated storage was also corrupted. I started another thread here for a different reason:

[UWP App Won't Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46880933/uwp-app-wont-start)

The answer that I needed to uninstall the app through powershell like this because the app somehow got installed with a different username:

```
Get-appxpackage -allusers <appname> | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Isolated storage now works. Magically, the compilation error I was getting with the same error message has cleared up as well. This is all still somewhat of a mystery.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know `IsolatedStorage` is not supported in Xamarin apps. You should use native storage mechanism on each platform to store files/data/settings - like described here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/ .

For UWP you will want to use `System.IO.File` or `Windows.Storage` to store and manage files.

Comment: We have been using isolated storage for a long time. If they've stopped supporting it, I'd like to see an article on it.

Comment: Aside from this, the error is coming up in a separate project at compile time which does not even use IsolatedStorage